# Clone input device with python-uniput

Tags: python, event-handling, keyboard

How can you clone a device with python-uniput?

I want to clone my keyboard:

1. read events from keyboard
2. print them to stdout
3. re emit the events

Library: http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/

Later I want to handle the events, but that's not part of this question.

Please leave a comment if you don't understand something in my question :-)

## Update

I found a great solution to it: [input-remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper). See my small article [Ten Flying Fingers (more comfortable touch typing)](https://github.com/guettli/ten-flying-fingers)

Comment: I think what you want to do is what function emit_click of python-uniput is doing.

Comment: AFAIK emit_click() does **create** an event. I want to grab all events from one device, do some processing and then emit the event.